# TensorFlow doesn't learn when input=output (or probably I am missing something)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have used TensorFlow before for training a model to recognize images (something similar to this example: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception). I was trying to do something similar with inception-v4 from scratch (using the model from https://github.com/tensorflow/models). But it was not working, it wasn't learning, so I decided to reduce my code and simplify everything. The model is a hidden layer with the same neurons as inputs and what the model has to learn is that input=output. Seems pretty simple and easy, but the results of my code are far from good.

I have tried different things: sigmoid cross entropy instead of softmax cross entropy, other optimizers, different learning rates, models more comples with more neuros and more layers, reduce_sum instead of reduce mean for the loss ... But the only times I got "good results" (>90%) it seems because the model falls into a local minimum and I am not able to replicate them. Usually I see 70% precision with a high loss (>=0.7).

My conclusion is that there is something wrong in my code that I am not able to spot and that is the reason the learning process is slow and get stuck at high losses. Otherwise the code with inception-v4 for images will at least learn something and don't get the loss stuck at the same value all the time.

```py
import os
import random
import shutil

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers

# parameters
max_steps = 10000
batch_size = 64
output_size = 10
summary_path = './summary'

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    shape = [batch_size, output_size]
    inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=shape, name='inputs')
    outputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=shape, name='outputs')
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    logits = layers.fully_connected(inputs, output_size)
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.1, global_step, max_steps / 3, 0.1,
                                               name='learning_rate')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, outputs, name='loss'))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    input_label = tf.argmax(inputs, axis=1) # vector with the input labels
    output_label = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1) # vector with the predicted labels
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', learning_rate)
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

# prepare summary
if os.path.exists(summary_path):
    shutil.rmtree(summary_path)
os.makedirs(summary_path)
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(summary_path, graph=graph)

with tf.Session(graph=graph).as_default() as session:
    session.run(init_op)
    to_run = {'step': global_step, 'loss': loss, 'logits': logits, 'train_op': train_op,
              'learning_rate': learning_rate, 'summary': summary_op,
              'in_label': input_label, 'out_label': output_label}
    step = 0
    while step < max_steps:
        # fake input
        data = np.zeros(shape, dtype=float)
        for i in range(batch_size):
            data[i, random.randint(0, output_size - 1)] = 1.0
        # run
        results = session.run(to_run, feed_dict={inputs: data, outputs: data})
        # print data
        step, in_label, out_label = results['step'],  results['in_label'], results['out_label']
        precision = (in_label == out_label).sum() * 100.0 / batch_size
        print('step: {0}/{1}  learning rate: {2:.4f}  loss: {3:.4f}  precision: {4:.1f}%'
              .format(step, max_steps, results['learning_rate'], results['loss'], precision))
        summary_writer.add_summary(results['summary'], step)
    # print last batch
    print(data)
    print(results['logits'])
    print(in_label)
    print(out_label)
    print('precision {}%'.format(precision))

summary_writer.flush()
```

[image: learning rate and loss graphs]

**UPDATE**

I think the issue is related of how backpropagation works and the effects of the relu layer and the softmax layer in the error. With min square error the network converges more often. Also smaller batch sizes helps.
So basically online stocastic backpropagation doesn't work well when there are repeated inputs in the batch, the errors seem to cancel somehow. So smaller batch sizes helps.

Relu + softmax makes the outputs to have similar and small probabilities and cross entropy makes the network to converge to this. A winner takes all strategy will have solved this problem. Probably this is why sigmoid works beter than softmax, but still have the problem of crossentropy.

**UPDATE 2:**

The real reason of the bad convergence is the weight initialization and how backpropagation works. The update of the weight when the output of the neuron is 0 or 1 are very different in magnitude. When the output is 1 the input weight with the value 1 and the bias weight are updated with a bigger number than when the output is 0, where the bias is updated in the other direction by a small factor. This makes the network to converge very very slowly, and with it is very dependent of the initialization of the weights.

Comment: Hi! glad you found out. He and Glorot are (AFAIK) the current state-of-the-art initialization models, see more here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/13362